# Flask looks for db locally when it's on another server

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to setup my Flask application to work with a database hosted on a different server. My whole setup works, if i try to work with a simple PyMysql script i will be able to connect to the database, but when i try to do that from Flask i get any kind of problem.

I'm keeping my db configurations on **config.py**:

`SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://user:pass@external_ip/mydb`'

But whenever i try to do a query, i will get the following error:

```
SELECT command denied to user 'user'@'local_ip'
```

So flask is looking for the db locally, for some reason, even though i set it to point to an external server. Can anyone help me out on this?

On the same environment, the following will connect and allow me to make queries:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host='external_ip', user='user', password='pass', db='mydb', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error looks more like a db server error, more then a local flask client error.

If it was a Flask local error of inability to connect to the mysql server you should end up with something like:

- Unable to connect to the server
- Hostname unreachable
- Connection refused (if you reach the server but with the wrong port, for instance)

Reading this error I guess that **you have reached the server, but for that user + IP + Database combination you have no read permissions**.

See the [GRANT Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) doc for further details

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you take a look to my edit? I tried to connect using PyMysql from the exact same environment and it connects

Comment: For  "same environment" you are meaning "the same server"? In that case is ok, I think "localhost" is the default for mysql as request source IP. e.g. 'user'@'localhost'. If you want to give access to all IPs you should have this grant on mysql server 'user'@'%' (naturally in a production environment is better to have grants for the exact IPs of your application server). If you haven't already, give a look at the GRANT doc a greater understanding of what's is going on inside mysql ;-)

Comment: Yes but what i don't understand is why can the pymysql script i added access the database while flask, that is on the same server and same everything can't?

Comment: The user too is the same, the only thing that changes is that the first time i'm using Flask to make a query, the second time i'm using a two lines python script that uses PyMysql to access the db

Comment: At this point I have no idea. For at least try to establish that is a mysql permission problem try to shut down the server and then check if the error change. If it does it means that the problem is really on the server side privileges side. Try then to do "SHOW GRANTS FOR <user>" and then try to understand why you are being blocked. Last try you can try to see mysql accesses log and try to understand why the request has been blocked